# Setting a null sting to "Missing"

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, nsstring, nsregularexpression

If it doesn't find a result how can i set the string to "Missing"

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d{4}-\\d{4}"options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *someString = result;
NSString *match = [someString substringWithRange:[expression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:someString options:NSMatchingCompleted
range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])]];
```

This code searches a string and extracts text.

Comment: What do you mean saying "set the string to Missing"

Comment: To make the string = missing text

Comment: if... else... you can do it easily with a IF condition for example.

Comment: `match = (match) ? match : @"MISSING TEXT";`

Comment: Can you please question little bit more clear.